# How to apply Semantic UI Javascript code for dynamically loaded element through Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, semantic-ui

Using Vue.js, I am trying to add more rows to my table on click of a button labeled as `Add new row`. The table rows contain Semantic UI Dropdowns. Everything is working fine but I am facing the following two issues:

1. In order to make the Semantic UI dropdown animation work in the newly added row, I have to append dropdown javascript code again after clicking `Add new row`. I have included the code on this link: https://www.grillies.ca/ui.js. You can also see the code that I am using to append the external js file in order to initialize the dropdown below. Is there any way I can make the animation work without appending external js after the `Add new row` button click? I have to use an external js file because it will have many functions like these for other Semantic UI elements. All I want is not to append the javascript code everytime I add new Semantic UI element dynamically.
2. The 2nd issue I am facing is that when I click on `Remove` button, only the last row gets removed. I want to only remove the row for which button has been clicked.

I looked for a lot of answers on StackOverflow but couldn't find anything similar.
Here is my code:

```js
// Vue js code starts
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    languages: [{
        name: "Learn JavaScript",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Learn Vue",
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: "Build something awesome",
        id: 4
      }
    ],
    rows: [1], //loops running by default
  },
  methods: {
    addMoreCombination() { //function for adding more rows
      this.rows.push({})
      //script to append external js start here
      let scriptForAppend = document.createElement('script')
      scriptForAppend.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.grillies.ca/ui.js')
      document.head.appendChild(scriptForAppend);
      //script to append external js ends here

    },

    deleteRow(index) {
      //function to remove that particular row
      this.rows.splice(index, 1)
    }

  }
})

//Semantic UI js Code to initialize the HTML dropdown (also included in https://www.grillies.ca/ui.js for appending after each click)
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">

    <table class="ui celled table">
      <tr v-for="(input, index) in rows" :key="index">
        <td>
          <select class="ui search dropdown">
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option v-for="language in languages" :key='language.id' :value="language.id">{{language.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="ui search dropdown">
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option v-for="language in languages" :key='language.id' :value="language.id">{{language.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td><button class="ui button red" @click="deleteRow(index)">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="ui basic button mb20 small" @click="addMoreCombination">
              Add new row
   </button>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's a [Vue ported version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-vue) of this library. There should be no need for script injection with it.

Comment: There is no animation in this library. For example, if I use accordion module in `https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html` there is a delay in hide-show and in `https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/modules/accordion` there is no delay in hide-show